# Sequelize js 'include' and 'raw'

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a relation between two entites like (every chest has one user)

```
entities.Chest.belongsTo(entities.User)
```

i want to retrieve all chests and their users in one query, so i do

```
entities.Chest.findAll({include:[{model: entities.User}]})
```

But i prefer to manipulate them as plain objects, i do

```
entities.Chest.findAll({raw:true, include:[{model: entities.User}]})
```

And the result does not include users at all, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as you see, raw has some problems with joins (there is an [issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6334))
try just use instance method [#toJSON](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/instance/#tojson-object)

```
entities.Chest.findAll({include:[{model: entities.User}]})
  .then(function(chestsSeq){
    var chests = chestsSeq.toJSON(); //same as chestsSeq.get({});
    //do something with raw chests object
  });
```

Answer (score 13):

This syntax helps for me. You haven't to iterate your records. Just use `nest: true` and `raw: true` in pairs;

```
entities.Chest.findAll({
    raw:true,
    nest: true,
    include:[entities.User]
})
```

Comment: Thanks. 'nest: true' is the required thing when using async and await.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!